# aptana html highlighting not working well

Tags: html, aptana, highlighting

I just downloaded Aptana (v3.0.4) and I'm really liking it, much better for coding than Dreamweaver. The big problem I've found so far is that I can't get the HTML highlighting to work properly.

For example, I go to the Theme selector and choose one theme (in this case the Dreamweaver theme, since I'm already used to those colors). It works fine for php, javascript, css... but for HTML. It won't give different colors to the different html tags (like **"a", "img", "form"**, etc). If I look at the colors palette, I can see that those tags have different colors assigned, but no matter what color they have in the palette, they take the color of the "html meta" element in the palette. So basically, ALL the tags have the same color, which is annoying.

Is there any way to fix this? I've even created a new theme copying the Dreamweaver one to make modifications, but still the same...

**EDIT**

It seems that this might have something to do with **Scopes**. The coloring rules work assigning a color to a certain scope (each coding element has one scope linked to it). In the colors palette, each of the html tags **("a","img",etc)** has a different scope linked to it. However, if I use the **Show Scope** tool that Aptana has, all those elements show the same scope: **text.html.basic meta.tag.block.any.html entity.name.tag.inline.any.html**, instead of showing a different one each one. So since they all have the same scope, using the them editor you can't choose a different color for each one... Is there any other way to do it? Is it possible to change the assigned scope of an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HTML tags currently have the same scope, so you can't (yet) do what you are asking. But please file a feature request so it can be added to the list.

Answer (score 4):

These operations behave similar to CSS Selectors.

**GO => entity.name.tag.inline.(form, img, p, etc.).html.**

(1)  **OPEN** the Preferences **Theme** Panel.

(2)  **ADD** (**+**) a **NEW** element.

(3)  **SELECT** your desired **STYLES**.

(4)  **PASTE** your desired **scope selector**, *e.g.,* "**entity.name.tag.inline.form.html**" **INTO** the **Scope Selector FIELD**… and **CLICK** ***'Apply'***.

(5)  **PRESTO CHANGE-O!**

Answer (score 0):

maybe check the default editor for html files in aptana?

Anyway, my aptana had always the same color for each tag.